# How to generate TMP InputField by script in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textmeshpro

In my project I have a canvas and now I want to spawn a `TMP_InputField` on it using script. For other things like `Image`, `TMP_Text`, etc. I simply generated a new `GameObject` and added the necessary components to it:

```cs
GameObject object = new GameObject("Object", typeof(Image));
object.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
```

But for `TMP_InputField` this doesn't work as expected. I can add the components to it and have an GameObject in my hierarchy but I don't know if I'm missing any components and how to link the ones I have up. Please help me. I can provide my code if requested although a clean and new solution would be more helpful.

Comment: Create an instance of an input field using the editor.  You will see there is much more to an input field than just a single script on a game object.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution, made a prefab with the component that you want to add, then instantiate the prefab on the canvas.

Example:

```
    public TMP_InputField inputFieldPrefab;
    private TMP_InputField instantiatedInputField;
    public Transform parent

    private void InstantiateInputFieldPrefab()
    {

        instantiatedInputField = Instantiate(inputFieldPrefab, parent);
        // do the setup on the instance 
    }
```